How can i insert a new option in InspectorControls
I have a wordpress plugin and i would like to insert a button in InspectorControls for blocks.
This is what i did but it doesn't work, no errors in the console or wordpress error log.
The javascript file is attached and running, selectedBlock is ok, the elements are created but do not appear.
My colleague GPT didn't know how to help me and i don't see where i went wrong
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', array('WP_UEA__main', 'add_js_functions'));


public static function add_js_functions()
    {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'ea-custom-settings',
        plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/ea-custom-settings.js',
        ['wp-block-editor', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-data', 'wp-plugins'],
        false,
        true
        );
    }

JavaScript file
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
    const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
    const { PanelBody, Button } = wp.components;
    const { createElement } = wp.element;
    const { useSelect, dispatch } = wp.data;

    registerPlugin('ea-custom-settings', {
        render: function () {
            const selectedBlock = useSelect((select) =>
                select('core/block-editor').getSelectedBlock()
            );

            // Function to add a unique class to the block
            const addUniqueClass = function () {
                const uniqueClass = `ea-tag-${Date.now()}`;
                if (selectedBlock) {
                    const { clientId, attributes } = selectedBlock;
                    const existingClasses = attributes.className || '';
                    const updatedClasses = `${existingClasses} ${uniqueClass}`.trim();
                    dispatch('core/block-editor').updateBlockAttributes(clientId, {
                        className: updatedClasses,
                    });
                    alert('Class added: ' + uniqueClass);
                }
            };

            return (
                selectedBlock &&
                createElement(
                    InspectorControls,
                    {},
                    createElement(
                        PanelBody,
                        { title: 'EA Options' },
                        createElement(
                            Button,
                            {
                                isPrimary: true,
                                onClick: addUniqueClass,
                            },
                            'Add EA Tag'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
        },
    });
});

